# Why is [mvp] a master tag and [mvc] only a synonym?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Why are `mvp` and `mvvm` master tags while `mvc` is only a synonym tag to the master tag `model-view-controller`?

Is there a good explanation for this that I'm missing? Wouldn't it make more sense that `mvc` is the master tag and `model-view-controller` is the synonym?

View the tags by going to [Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest) and enter the filter **model-**

Comment: Because [model-view-presenter] is a synonym for [mvp].  Crossed wires.  No tags were harmed in the process, they are too unspecific and serve only as contextual tags.  Usually along with a primary language or framework tag.

Comment: Because then even more people would tag questions [asp.net] [mvc] instead of [asp.net-mvc], and then complain they couldn't create [mvc-5].